# how to create watermark effect using jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, watermark

I got this [article](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/create_an_aspnet_textbox_watermark_effect_using_jquery.php) for doing this but i found that this is not working as i have given multiple classes in same textbox. How to convert this to work with multiple classes. I dont know how to use selectors to work with.

I am using it like this

```
<div class="inbox3full">
    <div class="threeinbg"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSortOrder" CssClass="threein water" 
            Text='<%# Bind("SortOrder") %>' runat="server" ToolTip="Type your Sort Order"></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
```

with jquery as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(function() {

            $(".water").each(function() {
                $tb = $(this);
                if ($tb.val() != this.title) {
                    $tb.removeClass("water");
                }
            });

            $(".water").focus(function() {
                $tb = $(this);
                if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
                    $tb.val("");
                    $tb.removeClass("water");
                }
            });

            $(".water").blur(function() {
                $tb = $(this);
                if ($.trim($tb.val()) == "") {
                    $tb.val(this.title);
                    $tb.addClass("water");
                }
            });
        });
   // });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**
 Sys is undefined.

```
.water{font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:75%; color:black;}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".water").addClass('watermark');
        $(".watermark").live('focus', function() {
            $tb = $(this);
            if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
                $tb.val("");
                $tb.removeClass("water");
            }
        }).live('blur', function() {
            $tb = $(this);
            if ($.trim($tb.val()) == "") {
                $tb.val(this.title);
                $tb.addClass("water");
            }
        }).blur();​
    });

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
      $(".water").not(document.activeElement).blur();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It should work even though it has multiple classes.

Comment: @Manticore: i added it explicitly. otherwise it was not mentioned in the code and i have tried both the ways although

Comment: Sorry, yes, saw the other line just after I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like you have, it's easier to just fire the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) handler, like this (edited to use `.live()` since you're adding them in an UpdatePanel):

```
$(function() {
  $(".water").addClass("watermark");
  $(".watermark").live('focus', function() {
    $tb = $(this);
    if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
        $tb.val("");
        $tb.removeClass("water");
    }
  }).live('blur', function() {
    $tb = $(this);
    if ($.trim($tb.val()) == "") {
        $tb.val(this.title);
        $tb.addClass("water");
    }
  }).blur();​
});
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YrecQ/4/). This puts the watermark/title in if the box was initially empty, which is usually what you want.  Also when your PanelPanel finishes you'll want to call `.blur()` on those elements again to apply the watermark to freshly created ones, like this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
  $(".water").not(document.activeElement).blur();
});
```

This will blur all elements except the currently focused one, as to not interrupt the user typing.

Comment: @Nick: I tried above code. It is not working with my code although it is working over the place you shown. :(

Comment: @Shantanu - Are your elements dynamically added, via an UpdatePanel or something?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I am adding controls dynamically. And also using UpdatePanel with ajax 3.5

Comment: @Shantanu - You need to use `.live()` for that then, one moment and I'll update.

Comment: @Nick: Does this `live()` works in both the cases or only if updatepanel is used

Comment: @Shantanu - It will work in both cases, it's a different approach to event handling.  The trade-off it's less efficient for a small number of elements, but not much so...you just don't want *everything* (I mean hundreds here, not for your small numbers) using `.live()`, each one adds an event handler to `document` that has to react to every event of that type, and check the selector against the event target.

Comment: @Nick: This script added by you has to be appended with the above script ?

Comment: I updated both scripts, make sure you're using the latest of the top.  The button tells your updatePanel to run that function when a request completes, so it's just executing the `blur` handler for new elements.  What isn't working, are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @Nick: I am not getting any error. My buttons and textboxes are being generated dynamically using formview control of asp.net. NO effect is visible. See my edit for details

Comment: @Shantanu - Ah! you need a `document.ready` wrapper, check the update answer above and give it a shot. Also make sure the `water` CSS class has some properties like in my demo page, `.water { color: #aaa; }` for example.

Comment: @Nick: After adding document.ready I am getting title in textboxes. But no blur effect is visible at this point. What is the role of `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` in the code. I have not added this line. Where it needs to be added

Comment: @Shantanu - It can be added anywhere, right after the other script is fine.  It's just telling it to apply the effect immediately to new controls added by the UpdatePanel.  As I said in the last comment though, the `water` CSS class needs some properties to see any visible effect, the class alone won't add any visual styling unless you give it some properties.

Comment: @Nick: First of all thanks for your patient. My css class is  `.water{font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:75%; color:black;}`

Comment: @Nick: When i clicks on textbox. content of textbox doesn't clears

Comment: @Shantanu - I had a complete brain lapse there try it now.  It was removing the `water` class (which was fine before) and breaking the `.live()` handler for `blur` because it's looking for it.  Adding a placeholder class that doesn't go away works, try the above it should solve the issue.

Comment: Didn't worked. I added my latest script and css that I am using.

Comment: @Shantanu - In the code included after all of the other script?  You can move it inside the `$(function() { });` wrapper to be safe.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for your support. I could not run this into my code. Dont know the reason so I am now using ajax watermark control in place of this but will try it at my home now.